# gradle nativeBinaries fails to satisfy dependencies

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlin-native

So, I wanted to generate native Kotlin binary for my app. I've came up with this build.gradle.kts:

```
plugins {
    application
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.3.70"
}

version = "1.0.2"
group = "org.gradle.sample"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    linuxX64("native") {
      binaries {
        executable()
      }
    }
  }

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
    implementation("io.javalin:javalin:3.8.0")
}
```

The code itself is simple:

```
package org.gradle.sample

import io.javalin.Javalin

fun main() {
    val app = Javalin.create().start(7000)
    app.get("/") { ctx -> ctx.result("Hello World") }
}
```

Problem here is that it fails when compiling, like if the dependencies were not satisfied:

```
> Task :compileKotlinNative FAILED
Caching disabled for task ':compileKotlinNative' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':compileKotlinNative' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has failed previously.
file or directory '/home/keddad/Documents/samplekotlinapi/src/commonMain/kotlin', not found
file or directory '/home/keddad/Documents/samplekotlinapi/src/commonMain/kotlin', not found
Run tool: konanc with args: -g -ea -target linux_x64 -p library -o /home/keddad/Documents/samplekotlinapi/build/classes/kotlin/native/main/basic-api.klib -Xmulti-platform -no-endorsed-libs /home/keddad/Documents/samplekotlinapi/src/nativeMain/kotlin/org/gradle/sample/Main.kt
e: /home/keddad/Documents/samplekotlinapi/src/nativeMain/kotlin/org/gradle/sample/Main.kt: (3, 8): Unresolved reference: io
e: /home/keddad/Documents/samplekotlinapi/src/nativeMain/kotlin/org/gradle/sample/Main.kt: (6, 15): Unresolved reference: Javalin
e: /home/keddad/Documents/samplekotlinapi/src/nativeMain/kotlin/org/gradle/sample/Main.kt: (7, 20): Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.
:compileKotlinNative (Thread[Execution worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.201 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Same thing worked when compiling for JVM, but for Native it breaks. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will not be able to compile this code at the moment. It seems like the `Javalin` framework is not targeting Kotlin/Native, it publishes only for Kotlin/JVM. The only libraries published with K/N in mind will be available to use. 
In fact, the problem is that Kotlin flavors are not equivalent internally. They can share pure Kotlin code via `common...` source sets, but one cannot take a Kotlin/JVM project and just change the target. Kotlin/Native differs from the Kotlin/JVM, both of them are not the same as the Kotlin/JS. To make them work together, an approach named Kotlin/Multiplatform is recommended, see [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multiplatform.html) article. 
If you are interested in adapting this code to become multiplatform, consider looking at the [Ktor](https://ktor.io). It provides support of the Kotlin/Native, and you'll be able to partially share code between platforms.